# creating a column of the average for groups of values in the same column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

This is a weird ask and sorry for butchering the title.
On tableau, I am able to create a column for averages of a certain Tier. and I was wondering if there was a function that would do the same in excel.
Here is an example of how I would like for it to look

[image]

Comment: I believe you are looking for [`AVERAGEIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690)

Comment: Wouldn't you have to use Averageif https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/averageif-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642 if you were using Excel 2010?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2010

```
=AVERAGEIF(A$2:A$16,A2,B$2:B$16)
```

[image]